# Assumptions for .equals() method in java - compare object's instance or object's state

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

What exactly recognise .equals() method in assumption: object's instance or object's state?

I am learning Hibernate and JPA. When I want to use bidirectional OneToMany association there is a problem because when I override equal and HashCode method with all variables there is become infinity loop. 
The only way to solve the problem which I see is to not use in one of the class the other class instance in equals() and hashCode().
So I am considering if it is compatible with assumptions in Java for .equals() method.

For example we have a Person class(). I know that email is unique value. So I can compare person by email and then I know that it is the same person (instance) but I don't know if the object's state is the same (firstName and lastName fields can differ).
So it is my question, what should we expect during compare object with .equals()?

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String email="";
    private String firstName = "";
    private String lastName = "";

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Person)) return false;
        Person person = (Person) o;
        return email.equals(person.email);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(email);
    }
}
```

Comment: From Object.equals doc: " @return  {@code true} if this object is the same as the obj argument; {@code false} otherwise."

Comment: Hi! I have read it in documentation before ask, but what does it mean that object is the same? For example we can't get under consideration id value because it is generated by database and is null as long as we don't save object to database.

Comment: Don't EntityMappings in JPA work with entity ids? Do they really need `equals` to be implemented?

Comment: JPA works properly without it but I need it to other reason and I want to be sure that I don't break any Java conception to avoid errors in work of frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I think of implementing `equals` for a given class I ask myself a question: what makes an object unique? What differs instance of one `Person` different from other? Then I use that properties for implementing `equals`. In your case, or in case of `@Entity` objects with `@XtoY` relationship, in my opinion there is no need to include this relationship to `equals`.

If for example I have a `Person` that has a relation to `Department`, the fact that a person belongs to some departments doesn't make his unique. It's his name/surname/PESEL or email and so on, and that's what I would include in `equals`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of equals() is :

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (this == obj);
    }
```

So your overridden equals() will return true if email is same.

Comment: Yes, but is is correct to skip over firstName and lastName? I ask because the method can be used frameworks to compare objects and we know that equal() define only the same object's instance then we know that we need to compare the fields if we want to be sure that object's the state is the same. But if in assumption the method should return true only if state is te same then we don't need to compare fields.

Comment: You have a valid point :
this may help you:
https://thoughts-on-java.org/ultimate-guide-to-implementing-equals-and-hashcode-with-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks, I have read it before but and there he use only natural key to compare objects, but I wasn't sure if it is right.